# Matrix diagonalization understanding gap

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have a fairly simple understading gap regarding the diagonlization process of a matrix which bothers me and ill be happy to receive an explanation regarding it or if perhaps I am mistaken then ofcourse correct me.

I understand the matrix digagonlization forumula -  P⁻¹MP = D , what I dont understand is why we stop where D main diagonal λx,λy,λz....λn are each a different value in the main diagonal and we dont continue and build a formula where the final matrix  is the identity matrix as we can 
P⁻¹MP × E1×E2...En elementry matrices get a final I identity matrix. 
P⁻¹MP × E1×E2...En = D× E1×E2...En = I 
Am I wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are wrong. The goal of diagonalization is to find a diagonal matrix $D$ *similar* to the original matrix $M$. If one of the $\lambda_k$'s is is different from $1$, then $M$ is *not* similar to the identity matrix. By the way, the only matrix similar to the identity matrix is the identity matrix itself.

Comment: Why if one of the λks are different than 1 it is not similar to the identity matrix ? 
I can set an elementary matrix which divides that row or column by λ and get it to be 1, so I can multiple P by that elementary matrix and P⁻¹ by the invert of that matrix so it still remains P⁻¹MP but now it would be P⁻¹MP = I , no  ?

Comment: No: $M$ and $P^{-1}MP$ have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: I apologize - I feel I have fundemntal gap which prevent me understanding diagonlilzation vs Gauss elimination - does Gauss elimination change the Eigenvalues of a matrix ? 
Meaning, when discussing Eigenvalues it must be regarding a specific matrix that has not been reduced to reduce echelon form ? 
Does a nXn matrix that can be diagonalized must be invertable or also multiple solutions matrix can be diagonalized ?

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.